# google sheet : create incremental number for multiple merged cells

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make incremental number in a column. When using formula , i can refer the cell before and add to 1 and it works (For example in A2 i can use A1+1 and copy down the formula to A3 to A500 ).

But in this case, i can't use formula because the cell has been merged randomly (Pls check the screenshot) , so i can't refer to previous cell.

I also try to manually select 2 last number (in this example 4 and 5 ) and drag that lower right corner handle and drag down, but the result will override the cell formatting. The previously setup merged cells will be destroy.

What is the best way to do it ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: if its really random you need to use a scripted solution. if merged cells are predictable it can be done with formula only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first merged range enter `1` and in the second enter formula:

```
=MAX($A$1:A2)+1
```

(change `A2` to cell address before second range - in your sample case `A4`), then copy formula, select desired range where to paste and `paste special` -> `formula only`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the layout you have it works. But i tried to another layout, the formula works, but when i copy that second cell and paste to a range , it skip some of rows. Here's example : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iDho1ZUkk1--979FQmW-x7jv6aQ_KVlbqZMhsCX-w6E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @andio Yes, this formula works if the cell to be copied is not merged. In your sample case, it would be A8, i.e. fill in the first three with 1,2,3 and then apply the formula ```=MAX($A$1:A7)+1```

Comment: As a note, using R1C1 notation makes it so you don't have to change it for each cell (works in any cell, expect for the first row): `=MAX(INDIRECT("R1C[0]:R[-1]C[0]",FALSE))+1`